# Making a cast in List<T>.Sort

Tags: c#, sorting

So I am having a list with objects. Those objects have a property TimeStamp. The problem is, this property is a string. Now when sorting the list by TimeStamp, the sort function ignores "AM" and "PM"

```
var historicalAlarms = new List<IHistoricalAlarmItem>();
foreach(...)
{ 
    ... 
}

historicalAlarms.Sort((x, y) => ((Belimed.Alarm.HistoricalAlarmItem)x).TimeStamp.CompareTo(((Belimed.Alarm.HistoricalAlarmItem)y).TimeStamp));
```

Is it possible to convert the TimeStamp to a new DateTime object to make the Sort function not ignore AM and PM? Remember that the objects in the List also need to be cast to another type (unfortunately they have the same name)

This works:

```
historicalAlarms.Sort((x, y) => ((Belimed.Alarm.HistoricalAlarmItem)x).ActivationTime.CompareTo(((Belimed.Alarm.HistoricalAlarmItem)y).ActivationTime));
```

This doesnt:

```
historicalAlarms.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse((Belimed.Alarm.HistoricalAlarmItem)x.TimeStamp))
```

Comment: Yes, you should convert the strings to DateTimes and compare them.

Comment: _"The problem is, this property is a string"_ A fault confessed is half redressed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OrderBy` and `DateTime.Parse` to achieve that.

```
historicalAlarms = historicalAlarms
    .OrderBy(value => DateTime.Parse(value.TimeStamp))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: And assign it back to the original variable. `OrderBy` doesn't modify the original list, `Sort` does.

Comment: Good, might need: historicalAlarms = historicalAlarms.OrderBy(value => DateTime.Parse(value.TimeStamp)).ToList();

Comment: I think you need a .ToList() on the end?

Comment: I have updated my question. There is still a problem

Comment: @user2877820 Don't forget that `OrderBy` doesn't change the list but returns a new one. You need to assign the return type back to the list.